# Android GridView неправильная очередность отрисовки при прокрутке и передача ID

Tags: android, gridview

Написал свой адаптер для `GridView`, но столкнулся с проблемой, что при скроллинге `GridView` елементы подгружаются в другой последовательности. Как следствие при клике на елемент `GridView` передается не тот ID из `ArrayList`. 
Как это исправить, чтобы нормально передать  ID элемента, на который кликнули и чтобы этот элемент совпадал с елементом в `ArrayList`?

MainActivity:

```
GridView gv;
gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Recipe " + (position + 1) +" selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Intent inent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RecipeView.class);
            inent.putExtra("recipeId", GridViewAdapter.recipe.get(position).getRecipeID());
            startActivity(inent);

        }
    });
```

GridViewAdapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
static ArrayList <Recipe> recipe = new ArrayList<>();

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList <Recipe> recipe) {
    this.context = context;
    this.recipe = recipe;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gv_main, null);

            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(recipe.get(position).getRecipeTitle());

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.food);

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return recipe.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return recipe.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}
}
```

GridView adapter layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_marginRight="20px"
        android:src="@drawable/food" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="40px" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/grid_item_image">
</TextView>
```

Comment: GridViewAdapter.recipe.get(position).getRecipeID() вот это правильный id дергает?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид это берет id из `ArrayList` в адаптере. То есть если кликнул на первый элемент `GridView` то берется первый id из `ArrayList`. При первом запуске все нормально, но если проскролить элементы в `GridView`, то очередность отрисовки элементов меняется и получается так, что первый елемент  уже другой, но id берется первого елемента `ArrayList`. А вот как исправить... Я в недоумении...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К коментарию выше добавлю это.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View customView = convertView;
        final Recipe recipeItem  = recipe.get(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            customView = li.inflate(R.layout.galery_item, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            customView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) customView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(recipeItem.getRecipeTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.food);

        return customView;

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
    }
```

Comment: Такой вариант работает. Элементы в GridView не меняют позиции, из за чего ІД передается правильный. Спасибо за подказку.

Comment: @YuraHalych незачто)